What did Rashi's comment on 1 Samuel 18:1 regarding a maskil being directed to an interpreter?
Rashi made this comment on Psalm 88:14:

a maskil: Wherever it says “maskil,” it was said through an interpreter. The prophet would set up an interpreter before him, and when he perceived a prophecy coming upon him, he would recite the prophecy to the interpreter, who would make it heard.

What might have been Rashi's source for this information? For example, I don't think I see anything about that in the Jewish Encyclopedia.

It's from the Talmud, Pesachim 117a:

"...״מַשְׂכִּיל״ — עַל יְדֵי תּוּרְגְּמָן..."
"...Psalms that begin with the word maskil were delivered by means of a disseminator, a spokesman in a public address..."


Wow, thanks, that answers the question. However, it raises another question. Which is the correct understanding, "interpreter" or "disseminator"?

@Ruminator the word "turgeman" which is used here as an interpretation of the word "maskil" literally means "translator" but generally refers to a "disseminator", someone with a loud voice who would recite someone else's speech out loud to the public. So, essentially, both translations - Chabad and Sefaria's - mean the same.
